# Return all nodes that are indirectly related to central node

Tags: python, neo4j, cypher

[image]

Hey guys! Im working with python py2neo and Im having trouble with returning "COMPRAN..." and "COMPRAS STREETW...", which as you can see are indirectly related to "Oscar" by the two closest note to "Oscar." My idea is to return a list with all nodes related to Oscar in the same way "COMPRAN..." and "COMPRAS STREETW..." are related.

The code Im trying is the following:

```
lista = []
for record in db.run("MATCH (a:user)-[:watched]->(b:video), (b)-[:hasTag]->(c:tag), (b)-[:hasGenre]->(d:genre), (e:video)-[:hasGenre]->(d:genre), (e:video)-[:hasTag]->(c:tag) WHERE a.name = $name RETURN e.name UNION MATCH (a:user)-[:watched]->(b:video), (b)-[:hasGenre]->(d:genre), (e:video)-[:hasGenre]->(d:genre) RETURN e.name UNION MATCH (a:user)-[:watched]->(b:video), (b)-[:hasGenre]->(d:genre), (e:video)-[:hasTag]->(c:tag) RETURN e.name", name=name, video=video, tag=tag, genre=genre):
    lista.append(record["e.name"])
    return lista
```

My problem is that it is only returning the node with the name "COMPRAS STREETW...", and my idea is that the query should return this node and "COMPRAN..." since they are related indirectly to "Oscar". Thanks for reading and hope you can help me get this to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This Cypher code *should* find both desired nodes:

```
MATCH
  (u:user)-[:watched]->(v1),
  (v1)-[:hasTag]->(t)<-[:hasTag]-(v2),
  (v1)-[:hasGenre]->(g)<-[:hasGenre]-(v2)
WHERE u.name = $name
RETURN v2.name
```